# Start Ubuntu Live Session on a HP Pavillon G6

Tags: live-usb

I cannot start a live session from a USB key, using Ubuntu 19.04. After selecting *Try Ubuntu without installing it*, I get a black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me :

- disable secure boot in the BIOS options
- when the option *Try Ubuntu without installing it* appears, press <kbd>E</kbd>
- in the second line ending with `quiet splash ---`. Delete `quiet splash ---` and replace with `nomodeset acpi=off`
- after that I could see command lines on the screen while the system was starting. But then I got this message fired repetitively :

  ```
  /init: line 7: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found
  ```

The solution was just to change the usb port used for the stick! I did it following the advice found [here on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/500822). It was previously plugged on the USB port on the right side of the computer, and I switched to the one that is farthest from you on the left side.

And I could finally start the live session.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to select boot from file then select efi after select grub to boot it